# Java 8 Supplier Exception handling with CompletableFuture

Tags: java, exception, java-8, completable-future

Consider the following code

```
public class TestCompletableFuture {

    BiConsumer<Integer, Throwable> biConsumer = (x,y) -> {
        System.out.println(x);
        System.out.println(y);
    };

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        TestCompletableFuture testF = new TestCompletableFuture();
        testF.start();      
    }

    public void start() {
        Supplier<Integer> numberSupplier = new Supplier<Integer>() {
            @Override
            public Integer get() {
                return SupplyNumbers.sendNumbers();                     
            }
        };
        CompletableFuture<Integer> testFuture = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(numberSupplier).whenComplete(biConsumer);         
    }       
}

class SupplyNumbers {
    public static Integer sendNumbers(){
        return 25; // just for working sake its not  correct.
    }
}
```

The above thing works fine. However `sendNumbers` could also throw a checked exception in my case, like:

```
class SupplyNumbers {
    public static Integer sendNumbers() throws Exception {
        return 25; // just for working sake its not  correct.
    }
}
```

Now I want to handle this exception as `y` in my `biConsumer`. This will help me in handling the result as well as exception (if any) inside a single function (`biConsumer`).

Any ideas? Can I use `CompletableFuture.exceptionally(fn)` here or anything else?

Comment: Here is a solution that allows you to use checked exceptions without reducing the readability of your code: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49705336/14731

Answer (score 16):

The factory methods using the standard functional interfaces aren’t helpful when you want to handle checked exceptions. When you insert code catching the exception into the lambda expression, you have the problem that the catch clause needs the `CompletableFuture` instance to set the exception while the factory method needs the `Supplier`, chicken-and-egg.

You could use an instance field of a class to allow mutation after creation, but in the end, the resulting code isn’t clean and more complicated that a straight-forward `Executor`-based solution. The [documentation of `CompletableFuture`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html) says:

> - All *async* methods without an explicit Executor argument are performed using the [`ForkJoinPool.commonPool()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ForkJoinPool.html#commonPool--) …

So you know the following code will show the standard behavior of `CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(Supplier)` while handling checked exceptions straight-forward:

```
CompletableFuture<Integer> f=new CompletableFuture<>();
ForkJoinPool.commonPool().submit(()-> {
  try { f.complete(SupplyNumbers.sendNumbers()); }
  catch(Exception ex) { f.completeExceptionally(ex); }
});
```

The documentation also says:

> … To simplify monitoring, debugging, and tracking, all generated asynchronous tasks are instances of the marker interface [`CompletableFuture.AsynchronousCompletionTask`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.AsynchronousCompletionTask.html).

If you want to adhere to this convention to make the solution even more behaving like the original `supplyAsync` method, change the code to:

```
CompletableFuture<Integer> f=new CompletableFuture<>();
ForkJoinPool.commonPool().submit(
  (Runnable&CompletableFuture.AsynchronousCompletionTask)()-> {
    try { f.complete(SupplyNumbers.sendNumbers()); }
    catch(Exception ex) { f.completeExceptionally(ex); }
});
```

Comment: could you explain what does this means?  (Runnable&CompletableFuture.AsynchronousCompletionTask)

Comment: @Jasonw: It’s a cast to an *intersection type*. In other words, the object must implement both types, `Runnable` *and* `CompletableFuture.AsynchronousCompletionTask`. Since type casts provide a context type for lambda expressions, this implies that the generated lambda instance will implement both interfaces. See also [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22808112/2711488)

Answer (score 7):

You are already catching the exception in `y`. Maybe you did not see it because `main` exited before your CompletableFuture had a chance to complete?

The code below prints "null" and "Hello" as expected:

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws InterruptedException {
  TestCompletableFuture testF = new TestCompletableFuture();
  testF.start();
  Thread.sleep(1000); //wait for the CompletableFuture to complete
}

public static class TestCompletableFuture {
  BiConsumer<Integer, Throwable> biConsumer = (x, y) -> {
    System.out.println(x);
    System.out.println(y);
  };
  public void start() {
    CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(SupplyNumbers::sendNumbers)
            .whenComplete(biConsumer);
  }
}

static class SupplyNumbers {
  public static Integer sendNumbers() {
    throw new RuntimeException("Hello");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I am not quite sure what you are trying to achieve. If your supplier throws an exception, when you call `testFuture .get()` you will get `java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException` caused by any exception that was thrown by the supplier, that you can retrieve by calling `getCause()` on `ExecutionException`.

Or, just as you mentioned, you can use `exceptionally` in the `CompletableFuture`. This code:

```
public class TestCompletableFuture {

    private static BiConsumer<Integer, Throwable> biConsumer = (x,y) -> {
        System.out.println(x);
        System.out.println(y);
    };

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        Supplier<Integer> numberSupplier = () -> {
            throw new RuntimeException(); // or return integer
        };

        CompletableFuture<Integer> testFuture = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(numberSupplier)
                .whenComplete(biConsumer)
                .exceptionally(exception -> 7);

        System.out.println("result = " + testFuture.get());
    }

}
```

Prints this result:

```
null
java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: java.lang.RuntimeException
result = 7
```

**EDIT:**

If you have checked exceptions, you can simply add a try-catch.

Original code:

```
Supplier<Integer> numberSupplier = new Supplier<Integer>() {
    @Override
    public Integer get() {
        return SupplyNumbers.sendNumbers();                     
    }
};
```

Modified code:

```
Supplier<Integer> numberSupplier = new Supplier<Integer>() {
    @Override
    public Integer get() {
        try {
            return SupplyNumbers.sendNumbers();                     
        } catch (Excetpion e) {
            throw new RuntimeExcetpion(e);
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: OP was hoping to be able to handle the exception in the code that invokes the supplier, rather than within the supplier itself.  If you are always going to handle the exception in a consistent way, it's clunky to be forced the try/catch in every supplier you write.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you could use new Object to wrap your integer and error like this:

```
public class Result {

    private Integer   integer;
    private Exception exception;

    // getter setter

}
```

And then:

```
public void start(){
    Supplier<Result> numberSupplier = new Supplier<Result>() {
        @Override
        public Result get() {
            Result r = new Result();
            try {
                r.setInteger(SupplyNumbers.sendNumbers());
            } catch (Exception e){
                r.setException(e);
            }
            return r;

        }
    };
    CompletableFuture<Result> testFuture = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(numberSupplier).whenComplete(biConsumer);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

## Just wrap the checked exception into a `CompletionException`

Another point to take into account with exception handling in `CompletableFuture` when using `completeExceptionally()` is that the exact exception will be available in `handle()` and `whenComplete()` but it will be wrapped in `CompletionException` when calling `join()` or when it is forwarded to any downstream stage.

A `handle()` or `exceptionally()` applied to a downstream stage will thus see a `CompletionException` instead of the original one, and will have to look at its cause to find the original exception.

Moreover, any `RuntimeException` thrown by any operation (including `supplyAsync()`) is also wrapped in a `CompletionException`, except if it is already a `CompletionException`.

Considering this, it is better to play it on the safe side and have your exception handlers unwrap the `CompletionException`s.

If you do that, there is no point anymore to set the exact (checked) exception on the `CompletableFuture` and **it is much simpler to wrap checked exceptions in `CompletionException` directly**:

```
Supplier<Integer> numberSupplier = () -> {
    try {
        return SupplyNumbers.sendNumbers();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new CompletionException(e);
    }
};
```

To compare this approach with [Holger's approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28961083/525036), I adapted your code with the 2 solutions (`simpleWrap()` is the above, `customWrap()` is Holger's code):

```
public class TestCompletableFuture {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        TestCompletableFuture testF = new TestCompletableFuture();
        System.out.println("Simple wrap");
        testF.handle(testF.simpleWrap());
        System.out.println("Custom wrap");
        testF.handle(testF.customWrap());
    }

    private void handle(CompletableFuture<Integer> future) {
        future.whenComplete((x1, y) -> {
            System.out.println("Before thenApply(): " + y);
        });
        future.thenApply(x -> x).whenComplete((x1, y) -> {
            System.out.println("After thenApply(): " + y);
        });
        try {
            future.join();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Join threw " + e);
        }
        try {
            future.get();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Get threw " + e);
        }
    }

    public CompletableFuture<Integer> simpleWrap() {
        Supplier<Integer> numberSupplier = () -> {
            try {
                return SupplyNumbers.sendNumbers();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                throw new CompletionException(e);
            }
        };
        return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(numberSupplier);
    }

    public CompletableFuture<Integer> customWrap() {
        CompletableFuture<Integer> f = new CompletableFuture<>();
        ForkJoinPool.commonPool().submit(
                (Runnable & CompletableFuture.AsynchronousCompletionTask) () -> {
                    try {
                        f.complete(SupplyNumbers.sendNumbers());
                    } catch (Exception ex) {
                        f.completeExceptionally(ex);
                    }
                });
        return f;
    }
}

class SupplyNumbers {
    public static Integer sendNumbers() throws Exception {
        throw new Exception("test"); // just for working sake its not  correct.
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Simple wrap
After thenApply(): java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: java.lang.Exception: test
Before thenApply(): java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: java.lang.Exception: test
Join threw java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: java.lang.Exception: test
Get threw java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.Exception: test
Custom wrap
After thenApply(): java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: java.lang.Exception: test
Before thenApply(): java.lang.Exception: test
Join threw java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: java.lang.Exception: test
Get threw java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.Exception: test
```

As you'll notice, the only difference is that the `whenComplete()` sees the original exception before `thenApply()` in the `customWrap()` case. After `thenApply()`, and in all other cases, the original exception is wrapped.

The most surprising thing is that `get()` will unwrap the `CompletionException` in the "Simple wrap" case, and replace it with an `ExecutionException`.

Comment: Throwing a `CompletionException` wrap is the key here, and makes everything run closer to the "`Future<?>` spirit"...