# Checked exception with CompletableFuture

Tags: java, asynchronous, java-8

Using `Java 8` great feature CompletableFuture, I'd like to transform my old async code using exceptions to this new feature. But the checked exception is something bothering me. Here is my code.

```
CompletableFuture<Void> asyncTaskCompletableFuture = 
                CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(t -> processor.process(taskParam));
```

The signature of `process` method:

```
public void process(Message msg) throws MyException;
```

How do I deal with that checked exception in ComletableFuture?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18198176/java-8-lambda-function-that-throws-exception - probably to be closed as a duplicate

Comment: @mjt I think this question is worth discussing in the context of CompletableFuture, as this API has a specific handling of exceptions.

Comment: The linked question is more general and, thus, covers this question too.

Comment: @Tunaki there might be more specific duplicates related to `CompletableFuture`, like http://stackoverflow.com/a/28961083/525036 and http://stackoverflow.com/q/23184964/525036 which both mention solutions involving `completeExceptionnally()` and avoiding to wrap the exception in a runtime exception.

Comment: Here is a solution that allows you to use checked exceptions without reducing the readability of your code: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49705336/14731

Comment: Maybe my implementation of throwing checked exception as unchecked ones is interesting for you.

https://github.com/qoomon/unchecked-exceptions-java

Looking forward for feedback

Answer (score 3):

I have tried this way, but I don't know whether it's a good way to solve the problem.

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface RiskEngineFuncMessageProcessor<Void> extends Supplier<Void> {
    @Override
    default Void get() {
        try {
            return acceptThrows();
        } catch (final Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    Void acceptThrows() throws Exception;
```

With the FunctionalInterface of Supplier, I can wrap the exception:

```
final MyFuncProcessor<Void> func = () -> {
            processor.process(taskParam);
            return null;
        };

        CompletableFuture<Void> asyncTaskCompletableFuture =
                CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(func)
                        .thenAccept(act -> {
                            finishTask();
                        })
                        .exceptionally(exp -> {
                            log.error("Failed to consume task", exp);
                            failTask( exp.getMessage());
                            return null;
                        });
```

Comment: `Void` is a class from the JDK. You should not use it as a type parameter name in your interface definition. Either remove it (as it does not seem to be useful here), or use another name. Single-letter names are commonly used, I'd suggest to use `T` as it is the name used in the `Supplier` interface definition.

Comment: It also seems that you do not need to return any results, so you should probably use [`runAsync()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#runAsync-java.lang.Runnable-) instead of `supplyAsync()`, and [`thenRun()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#thenRun-java.lang.Runnable-) instead of `thenAccept()`.

Comment: I recommend to throw [`CompletionException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/?java/util/concurrent/CompletionException.html) instead of an unspecific `RuntimeException`. I’ll work smoothly with `CompletableFuture`.