# How to throw a checked exception within CompletableFuture?

Tags: java, exception, java-8, completable-future, checked-exceptions

I used a static method `supplyAsync()` to get a `CompletableFuture`, and call its `whenComplete()` method to deal with the result and exception.

`whenComplete()` accepts a `BiConsumer` as parameter, and `BiConsumer`'s second parameter is a `Throwable`. But I found that I can't throw a checked exception in `supply()` method. If I did, Idea will show a tip “*Unhandled exception: java.lang.exception*”.

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    Integer i = 0;


    // unhandled exception
    CompletableFuture<Integer> future = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> CompletableTest.getInt(i), executorService);
    future.whenComplete((res, e) ->
    {
        System.out.println("res is " + res);
        System.out.println("e is " + e);
    });

}

public static Integer getInt(Integer i) throws Exception {
        Thread.sleep(3000);
        return i + 1;
}
```

I'm confused, `whenComplete()` can deal with checked exception, but I can't throw it.

Is it possible to throw a checked exception within `CompletableFuture`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Checked exception with CompletableFuture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39340239/checked-exception-with-completablefuture)

Comment: Other candidates: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28959849/java-8-supplier-exception-handling/28961083#28961083  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23184964/jdk8-completablefuture-supplyasync-how-to-deal-with-interruptedexception  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18198176/java-8-lambda-function-that-throws-exception

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java 8 Supplier Exception handling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28959849/java-8-supplier-exception-handling)